# How do you query for 'not null' or 'not empty' in azure storage explorer

Tags: odata, azure-storage

The azure storage explorer GUI seems to allow for queries where you match on string
with =,<,>,<>

but since `<> ''` or `eq null` does not seem to work I wonder:

is there a way to do an ODATA filter like the SQL equivalent
`where ColumnName != ''`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Querying 'not null' is not feasible, but you can use `ColumnName eq ''` or `ColumnName ne ''` to compare with empty string.